# Return value from a partial view loaded on a jquery dialog

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui-dialog, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a partialview "selectUser".  On this partial view a user can search for other users.  The user id will be stored in a hidden field or as a `var` on my view.  I need to use this partial view in many places.  Lets say I need to return the id of the selected user on the close event of my dialog.  My question is, how do I make this partial view, loaded as a modal dialog with jquery ui, to retrun the selected value to its parent view?  Is there a way to access the value directly from the parent view?

Comment: are you loading the partial view into the parent page and then displaying it with jquery?

Comment: yes but not sure if that the best way to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I follow what you are needing now.  So on your button click you do an ajax call back to the server and include the destination field name in the call

```
$.ajax({
     url: "@(Url.Action("Action", "Controller"))",
     type: "POST",
     cache: false,
     async: true,
     data: { destination: 'fieldName' },
     success: function (result) {
         $(".Content").html(result);
         AttachScript();
         Dialog.load();
     }
});
```

On your controller send that field to the partial view through your view model or viewbag and on the partial view put that field name in a hidden field.  then in your button click you should be able to do something like this (untested)

```
function AttachScript(){
    $('.btnSubmit').on('click', function(){
        var data = $('.sharedField').val();
        $($('.HiddenField').val()).val(data);
    });
}
```

which will set the value of whatever field is named in your hidden field to the data.  Hopefully this helps.

Comment: need to take a look on overlay.load() and attachScript, no idea wath they do XD

Comment: any link or tutorial to folow? im a litle lost

Comment: where are you stuck at?  Do you have the partial loaded and showing in your dialog?

Comment: yes and the value is stored on a hidden field or in a js var, so on the close method i can use it (but it didnt look clean), also ill be using this same dialog to feed diferent fields on my parrent view, so i need to find a way to it

Comment: Please see my changed answer above

Comment: ended doing somting similar